# Laravel - Validate only letters, numbers and spaces using regex

Tags: regex, validation, laravel

I am trying to validate a field made ​​up of letters, numbers and spaces in this way:

```
$rules = array(
    'field'=> 'regex:/([A-Za-z0-9 ])+/'
);
```

but if I try to insert characters like ' " and others, the validation still has to be successful.

What's wrong 'in my regular expression?

Comment: I'm confused. In your question, you say you only want to allow letters `A-z`, numbers `0-9` and space. Then, you say it should still succeed if there is `'` or `"`. Could you clarify?

Comment: You may need to anchor it to the beginning and end of the string with `^` and `$`: [`^[A-Za-z0-9 ]+$`](http://regex101.com/r/rV7xW6/1)

Answer (score 18):

```
$rules = array(
    'field'=> 'regex:/(^[A-Za-z0-9 ]+$)+/'
);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are working with utf-8

```
$rules = array(
    'field'=> 'regex:/(^[\pL0-9 ]+$/u'
);
```

Comment: helpful answer, you just forgot to add ")", anyway  here is the correction for who gonna face the same problem : regex:/(^[\pL0-9 ]+)$/u