# White Spaces Validation on Blade Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I'm creating a from like this :

```
{!! Form::text('name', null, [
              'class' => 'form-control',
              'placeholder'=>'Name',
              "required" => "required|regex:/(^[A-Za-z0-9]+$)+/",
              'maxlength' => 55,
              'minlength' => 5                  
              ])
!!}
```

I want to make sure that user can't input just blank space more than five times. But this regex:/(^[A-Za-z0-9]+$)+/ doesn't work. Everytime I input space more than 5 times, it's always valid. So How to prevent this thing...???

I have tried  `'field'=> 'regex:/(^[A-Za-z0-9 ]+$)+/'`from this link : [Laravel - Validate only letters, numbers and spaces using regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26720865/laravel-validate-only-letters-numbers-and-spaces-using-regex). It didn't work for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I found the answer :

```
  {!! Form::text('name', null, [
         'class' => 'form-control',
         'placeholder'=>'Name',
         "required" => 'required',
         'maxlength' => 55,
         'minlength' => 5,
         'pattern' => ".*\S+.*"
         ])
     !!}
```

So I just need to add `'pattern' => ".*\S+.*"` then blank space/white space will be seen as an invalid input.